# Finding a quotient series as far as x^3?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Ok so I honestly have no idea how to even approach this question, or really even what it's asking. I can't find mention anywhere in my prof's notes of a problem that looks like this. I don't even recognize any pattern... is this some sort of weird power series I just don't understand? How do I approach this?

It's not letting me post pictures but the question wants the coefficients for the first 4 terms of the series, it looks approximately like this:

$$\frac{1-4x+2x^2-5x^3+x^4+...}{1-3x-6x^2-2x^3-x^4+...}$$
$=$____ $+$____ $x+$___ $x^2+$____ $x^3$

Comment: Does it help you to mention that the answer is the first 4 terms of the MacLaurin series (Taylor series at $0$) for the rational function?

Answer (score 1):

Use division of the numerator by the denominator along the increasing powers of $x$ (not Euclidean division)!

For an example, you can look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422982/what-is-the-expansion-in-power-series-of-x-over-sin-x/1423125#1423125).

Answer (score 0):

Never forget you can do long division with polynomials

[image]

Comment: This is not long division!

Comment: I call it long division.

Comment: It is division along the increasing powers of $x$. It uses the notion ot order of a power series (degree of the 1st non zero term of the series).

Comment: I call it long division, too. It exactly follows the algorithm of long division, and proceeds exactly like long division of real numbers (consider $x = 1/10$).